# Old pseudo record in After Insert Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I've got the following test trigger which I copied from a book:

```
TRIGGER bef_ins_ceo_comp
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON ceo_compensation
   FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ceo_comp_history
        VALUES (:NEW.name,
                :OLD.compensation, :NEW.compensation,
                'AFTER INSERT', SYSDATE);
   COMMIT;
END;
```

As you can see when inserting a new record to the ceo_comp_history table :OLD.compensation value is used. I wonder where does that :OLD pseudo record come from? It's not an update trigger to keep both :NEW and :OLD values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the `:OLD` values will be all NULL. Code is probably just a copy/paste from the update trigger

Comment: Yeah, the author then himself implies that there's not OLD record for insert trigger.